# Unusual use of module namespacing

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I am familiar with modules giving a class access to instance methods included in the module, but I have not seen modules giving classes access to local variables.

Here is file `A`:

```
module SequelPlayground
  class Article
    attr_reader :title, :body, :author_id, :id
    def initialize(attributes)
      @title         = attributes[:title]
      @body          = attributes[:body]
      @author_id = attributes[:author_id]
      @id            = attributes[:id]
    end
    def self.next_id
      table.count + 1
    end
    def self.table
      DB.from(:articles)   #SELECT * FROM articles
    end
  end
end
```

Here is file `B`:

```
module SequelPlayground
  DB = Sequel.postgres("sequel-playground")

  class Server < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      erb :index
    end
  end
end
```

Why does file `A` have access to the local variable `DB`? Are anything within a module in the same namespace even across files?

Comment: `DB` is a module-level constant, not a local variable (by uppercase convention)

Comment: Ruby will resolve it, I believe, at local scope then search upward through the class, modules, up to global scope.

Comment: Interesting... I never knew that before. So in File A, it searches for DB locally, then the module, then globally?

Comment: Yes - since it starts with an uppercase letter, Ruby assumes it to be a constant and searches upward in scope until it finds it (or doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does file `A` have access to the local variable `DB`?

Because it's not a local variable. Local variables start with lowercase letters. It's a constant, because it starts with an uppercase letter.

Constants are looked up both lexically in the current scope and all enclosing scopes (similar to local variables in nested blocks, for example) and dynamically in the current class or module and all its superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`DB` is a module level constant. that is why it is accessible in both the files.